# Can't visit static variable of parent class in Dart?

Tags: dart

Dart code:

```dart
main() {
    print(PPP.name);
    print(CCC.name);
}

class PPP {
    static String name = "PPP";
}

class CCC extends PPP {
}
```

It prints:

```dart
PPP
Unhandled exception:
No static getter 'name' declared in class 'CCC'.

NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'name'
Receiver: Type: class 'CCC'
Arguments: [...]
```

So it's not available to visit static variables of parent class in Dart?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From Dart Programming Language Specification:

The `static members` of a class are its static `methods`, `getters`, `setters` and `static variables`.

- `Superclass static members` are `not in scope in subclasses`, and `do not conflict` with `subclass members`.
- Static members are `never inherited`.
- Static members `never override anything`.

---

So if you declare some static members in superclass then these members are not inherited in subclasses.

They remain in that class where they declared and do not conflicts with other declarations static members in the subclasses.

---

Q: Can't visit static variable of parent class in Dart?

A: Static variable of parent class cannot be accessed (as its own) in child class because it does not exists (not inherited) in child class.